# Calculating FV (future value) of a Uniform Stream using TVM (time value of money) in R

Tags: r, finance

I am perplexed. The problem I am working on (using financial package in R) is ,

Question : How much money must Carol deposit every year starting 1 year from now at 5.5 % per year in order to accumulate $6000 seven years from now?

My correct solution is :

```
> 6000/usfv(5.5,7)
[1] 725.7865
```

I think this should also work... but does not:

```
> tvm(i=5.5,n=7,fv=-6000,pmt=NA,pyr=1)

Time Value of Money model

   I% #N PV    FV    PMT Days #Adv P/YR C/YR
1 5.5  7  0 -6000 687.95  360    0    1    1
```

I am getting a difference PMT amount. Does anyone have an insight in why I a getting the difference

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2012q4/010851.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to check the numbers manually and playing with the indices helped me understand what is going on:

```
p1 <- 6000 / usfv(5.5,7)
```

matches the expectation that

```
sum(p1*(1 + 5.5/100)^(0:6))
# [1] 6000
```

For

```
p2 <- tvm(i=5.5,n=7,fv=-6000,pmt=NA,pyr=1)[1,"PMT"]
```

you have to change the time of the cashflows to get

```
sum(p2*(1 + 5.5/100)^(1:7))
# [1] 6000
```

In other words, `usfv` assumes cashflows at times 1 through 7 while `tvm` assumes cashflows at times 0 through 6 (and both functions assume future value is at time 7.)

P.S.: when testing my intuition, I also found that both functions cannot work with a zero interest rate (one returns NaN, the other errors out.) These on top of the useless documentations: I would not recommend that package...

Comment: thanks... I wonder how I can make tvm behave the same way as usfv